# Integral of the Exponential of a Cubic Polynomial

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

My problem involves finding a relatively simple expression for the integral

$$  I(a,b) = \int_0^{\infty} \text{d}x \: e^{-iax-bx^3}, $$

where $a$ is real, and $b$ is both real and positive.

I realise that there are closed form expressions for this; I have plugged this into Mathematica/WolframAlpha, which yields a combination of a Hypergeometric function and an AiryBi function. However, as a physicist (*gasp*), I would like to be able to evaluate the integral in terms of functions that I have a better intuition for how they behave, such as Gamma functions, exponential or trigonometric functions.

My first attempt was to expand the $e^{-iax}$ term as a series, and use the result that

$$\int_0^\infty \text{d}x \: x^n e^{-\beta x^{\alpha}} = \frac{1}{\alpha}\beta^{-\frac{n+1}{\alpha}}\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{\alpha}\right), $$

for integer $n$. This yields the result that

$$I(a,b) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-ia)^n}{3} b^{-\frac{n+1}{3}} \frac{1}{n!} \Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{3}\right), $$

which - I believe - converges nicely (assuming that $b$ is non-zero). Can I simplify this result further in terms of other functions? Can anyone improve on this attempt?

Comment: In terms of intuition, you could look at the partial sums of $I(a,b)$, in order to find the controlling factor of $I(a,b)$. Your series expansion is around $a = 0$. From the $n=0$ term, we learn that (for $a \to 0$) the real part of the integral scales like $\text{constant }\times b^{-1/3}$ and from the $n=1$ term we learn that the imaginary part like $a b^{-2/3}$ . It is also worth noting that the expansion is in non-integer powers of $b$.

Comment: ConditionalExpression[
 1/(18 b) (4 (-1)^(1/4) Sqrt[a] Sqrt[
     b] \[Pi] (BesselJ[-(1/3), -(((1/3 - I/3) Sqrt[2/3] a^(3/2))/Sqrt[
         b])] - BesselJ[1/
        3, -(((1/3 - I/3) Sqrt[2/3] a^(3/2))/Sqrt[b])]) - 
    3 a^2 HypergeometricPFQ[{1}, {4/3, 5/3}, (I a^3)/(27 b)]), 
 Im[a] < 0 && Re[b] > 0]